# How to prevent pasting over validation drop down cell in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to stop the user from pasting over my validation drop down cell. I have read and tried various solutions, none of which work just right. This code I have checks if the pasted value follows validation rules, but it doesn't work if the entire cell is pasted over my validation cell (it seems that this event fires after the paste, so the validation gets erased together with the previous cell):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In Range("D2:F13")
    If Not Cell.Validation.Value Then
        MsgBox "Value violates validation rule"
        Application.Undo
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next
```

Ideally the code would check if the value of the cell that's being pasted matches validation dropdown options and only allows to paste the value (not the formatting) into the cell.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the Cut\Copy in the specific cell:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' TARGET IS YOUR VALIDATION CELL
    If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row = 1 Then
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Or more complex you can try to check the clipboard of the user on `SelectionChange`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    ' TARGET IS YOUR VALIDATION CELL
    If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row = 1 Then

        Set MyData = New DataObject
        MyData.GetFromClipboard

        'In MyData.GetText you have the clipboard data in text format
        If MyData.GetText <> "what you want" then
            '...
        End if

    End If
End Sub
```

In this case you must add a reference to `Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library`. You can find it in this path: `C:\Windows\System32\FM20.DLL`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, I used your first method.

Comment: First method is great, THANKS :)